# How do I identify an oblique surface mesh?

Tags: crystallography, surfaces, space-groups

I have drawn three surface meshes from a hexagonal material for the $(0001)$, $(1\bar{1}00)$ and $(1\bar{1}01)$.
The first one would be the top horizontal surface of the hexagonal structure, the second a vertical rectangular surface from one of the walls, and the third one would be a rectangle at an angle to intersect the c-axis.

**But does this mean then that this last one is oblique because it is inclined to intersect the c-axis? How do I identify an oblique surface mesh?**

The definition I have been given for an oblique surface mesh is that "*it doesn't have a 90 degree angle between the basis vectors.*" but what are the basis vectors? Are there the $a_1, a_2,a_3, c$ vectors? If so, aren't these always the same independent on the surface of the crystal?

I believe that these meshes are rectangular but I am not entirely sure and would like to know if there are any sources I can check to learn the subject better.

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful if you could post images as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any, but I am basing my understanding it from an hexagonal structure shown in the following link : https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Sirona_Valdueza-Felip/publication/281452125/figure/fig5/AS:651951398199308@1532448734877/Hexagonal-unit-cell-The-c-plane-0001-m-plane-1-100-and-a-plane-11-20.png

Comment: The surface is equal to the one present on te right hexagonal structure on figure 3.24 on https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/one-slip-system-hcp-crystal-structure-0001-manner-similar-f-chapter-8-problem-8qp-solution-9781118061602-exc

Comment: @HitanshuSachania Are the links provided by the user sufficient to help you try to answer the question? This question has gone unanswered for about 3 months and I'm trying to help shorten the unanswered queue!

Comment: @NikeDattani sorry, don't have the expertise to answer this question. That was only a general suggestion.